# Set Interval in Time series to 1 second

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, visualization, monitoring, grafana

I am trying to display logs from elastic search in grafana using the lucene query. It works overall but I will like to set the interval in the time series as 1 second but from the grafana ui it seems the lowest limit I can set is 10 seconds. How do I limit the interval to just 1 second.
The lucene query is `log.file.path:\/data\/gitlab\/logs\/gitlab-rails\/api_json.log AND fields.environment:production`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that `Interval` select box, where the minimal value is `10s` is not real select box. You can click there and you can write/create `1s` there:

[image]

You can use this feature in other Grafana select boxes as well. It is just not intuitive feature for new users.